# Corona SDK in Wine gives blackscreen

Tags: wine

wine-5.8

Corona-2020.3582.msi
Test project https://github.com/coronalabs/GettingStarted01/archive/master.zip
from: https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/programming/01/index.html

I had to `sudo apt install libgl1:i386` also.

When trying to run the test project I always get a blackscreen.
Even after removing most of the code and only showing the background.
From winetricks, I tried also: nothing(only opengl), d3dx9, d9vk, dxvk (this one won't work on my notebook graphics card, the log shows error messages saying that)

So, were you able to run it? if so, did you do anything different from that?

Testing OpenGL (just to see if it works at all, and it did):

```
GlMark2 Score: 186  
GL_VENDOR:     Intel Open Source Technology Center  
GL_RENDERER:   Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile   
GL_VERSION:    2.1 Mesa 19.2.8
```

on desktop PC with nvidiaGT710 I get this error:

```
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadFBConfig
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  22 (X_GLXCreatePixmap)
```

Comment: Corona, the new virtue seti@home....

Comment: I think the problem is that my gfx card OpenGL version is too old compared to the requirements of this SDK. I think OpenGL hardware acceleration can be disabled on the X server and I could run another X instance where the SDK would work thru software rendering, but slower. Could not test these things yet tho...